# angular material layout conditional include

Tags: angularjs, layout, angular-material

I am trying to understand Angular Material layout. I have a section of HTML that is always floated to the right and it contains several lines in a column. That section is rendered as expected when using a smaller device. However, when the device is a small hand-held, in addition to adjusting the right-floating section, I don't want to include some of the lines in that column.

For example, on a large screen device the layout would be:

```
left-panel   middle-panel  right-panel-line 1
                           right-panel-line 2
                           right-panel-line 3
```

and then on a small screen device the layout would be:

```
left-panel
middle-panel
right-panel-line 1
```

where the 2nd and 3rd lines in the right-floating panel is not displayed.

Question: how do I conditional use the Angular Material layout directives to do this?

Thanks,
-Andres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Available Plunker [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaQmmL)

As you can see in `angular-material` layout extra options [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options), you can conditionally show and hide elements depending on the screen size.

[image]

Code for reference, see [plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaQmmL) for the complete details:

```
  <div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
    <div flex>left-panel</div>
    <div flex>middle-panel</div>
    <div layout="column" flex>
      <div flex>right-panel-line 1</div>
      <div flex hide-xs>right-panel-line 2</div>
      <div flex hide-xs>right-panel-line 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/zKrgXB)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout-gt-xs="row" layout-xs="column">
  <div style="background:red" flex></div>
  <div style="background:green" flex></div>
  <div flex layout="column">
    <div style="background:purple" flex></div>
    <div style="background:yellow" flex hide-xs></div>
    <div style="background:cyan" flex hide-xs></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to use layout and hide depending on screen size.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options

Comment: It seems to be that both have answered at the same time :)